# Finding out specific input values on key up from the same table row

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following form. What I am trying to do is when the value of `rate[]` is changed I want to get the value of the changed value and the value of `product[]` using jquery.

For example: if I change the value of rate[] (from the first row of the table) to 100, I want to get the new value of rate[] ..100 and its product_id[].. 1001

```
<form id="myform">
  <table>
     <tr>
         <td>Product 1</td>
         <input type="hidden" name="product_id[]" value="1001" />
         <td><input type="text" name="rate[]" value="2" /></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="10" /></td>
     </tr>

    <tr>
         <td>Product 2</td>
         <input type="hidden" name="product_id[]" value="1002" />
         <td><input type="text" name="rate[]" value="2" /></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="10" /></td>
     </tr>
  <table>
</form>
```

My JQuery code;

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(":text[name='rate[]']").bind("keyup", function() {

     // What to write here?

 });
```

Could you please help me to write the jquery code to find out those values?

Thanks :)

Comment: Your markup is invalid. Your product_id input box should ideally be inside a TD, instead of being after a TD in the same level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
var productID = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name^="product_id"]').val();
```